# Concatenate values in one column after the value of another column is unique

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have a tibble that looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(table_name = c("horse", "x", "x", "x", "dog", "x", "rat", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"),
             value_str = c(NA, "a", "b", "c", NA, "a", NA, "b", "d", "e", "f", "g"))
```

```
    > df
    # A tibble: 12 x 2
        table_name value_str
         <chr>      <chr>    
    1 horse      <NA>     
    2 x          a        
    3 x          b        
    4 x          c        
    5 dog        <NA>     
    6 x          a        
    7 rat        <NA>     
    8 x          b        
    9 x          d        
   10 x          e        
   11 x          f        
   12 x          g
```

I want to produce separate vectors for "horse", "dog", and "rat" that contain the strings from `value_str` in the rows below "horse" until "dog", "dog" until "rat", and "rat" until the end. I want the output to look like the following vectors:

```
vec_horse <- tibble(horse = c("a", "b", "c")) %>% pull(., horse)
vec_dog <- tibble(dog = c("a")) %>% pull(., dog)
vec_rat <- tibble(rat = c("b", "d", "e", "f", "g")) %>% pull(., rat)
```

```
    > vec_horse
    [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

I would do `group_by()` for `df$table_name`, but it doesn't work in this case, since it's about the position of the values of `df$value_str`.

I can't collapse `df$value_str` into a single vector, because the output needs to be separate vectors for each of the unique categories in `df$table_name`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = df %>%
    mutate(table_name = if_else(table_name == "x", NA_character_, table_name)) %>%
    fill(table_name) %>%
    group_by(table_name) %>%
    summarise(value_str = list(unique(value_str[!is.na(value_str)]))) %>%
    ungroup()

setNames(d$value_str, d$table_name)
```

Comment: This worked - the only thing I needed to change after the fact was removing the commas and splitting the string results in  `value_str`. I did this by adding: `mutate(value_str = str_remove_all(value_str, ",")) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  pull(2) %>% 
  strsplit(., " ") %>%
  unlist() `. Then my output is, in this example, just the values for "horse". I will now loop through this to create separate string vectors for "horse", "rat", "dog". If you would take a different approach to this last part, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to create three objects in the global env, one option is (not recommended)

```
lst1 <- lapply(split(df$value_str, paste0("vec_", 
   zoo::na.locf(replace(df$table_name,  df$table_name== "x", NA)))), 
        function(x) unique(na.omit(x))) 
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
vec_dog
#[1] "a"
vec_horse
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
vec_rat
#[1] "b" "d" "e" "f" "g"
```